# Need to parse utf8 email with perl

Tags: perl, email, utf-8, mime-types, mime

I need to parse an email that appears to be encoded using utf-8 to pull out the subject and sender and pieces of the body.

The header parts are no problem, but the body looks like this:

```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...
```

Alpine can apparently decode it properly, and tells me:

```
[ The following text is in the "utf-8" character set. ]
[ Your display is set for the "ANSI_X3.4-1968" character set.  ]
[ Some characters may be displayed incorrectly. ]
```

Which perl module can I use for this? Hopefully this is enough to help.

I see modules to create MIME-encoded messages, but how do I decode and read one? Do I need a module for this specific type of encoding?

Comment: Your email will have a line describing what MIME type this is. What does it say?

Comment: use [Mime::Tools](https://metacpan.org/release/MIME-tools), especially the [Mime::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Parser) class.

Comment: It says the following:

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of encodings happening here based on the Content-type in the comments. The body has been Base-64 encoded, which allows the email to represent arbitrary data as ASCII. The other is that the data underneath the Base64 encoding is UTF-8 encoding.

Something like [Email::MIME](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Email::MIME) should be able to handle this without you worrying about the details.